# Typescript interfaces for nested objects

Tags: typescript, ngrx

```
{
    data: {
        user: {
            selected: 1502205502995,
            entities: {
                11: {
                    actual: {id: 11, name: 'User A changed'},
                    persist: {id: 11, name: 'User A'},
                    validationError: {},
                    serverError: {},
                    products: {
                        selected: 1,
                        entities: {
                            1: {
                                actual: {id: 1, description: 'Description of product changed'},
                                persist: {id: 1, description: 'Description of product '},
                                deleted: true,
                                validationError: {},
                                serverError: {}
                            },
                            1502205955851: {
                                actual: {description: 'Description of product 2'}
                            }
                        },
                        list: {
                            page: 1,
                            page_count: 1,
                            page_size: 20,
                            total_items: 6,
                            items: [
                                {id: 1, description: 'Description of product '},
                                {id: 1, description: 'Description of product 2'}
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    notes: {
                        entities: {}
                    }
                },
                23: {
                    actual: {id: 23, name: 'Karik Guna'},
                    persist: {id: 23, name: 'Karik Guna'},
                    validationError: {},
                    serverError: {}
                },
                1502205502995: {
                    actual: {name: 'Karan Gupta'},
                    validationError: {},
                    serverError: {},
                    address: {
                        entities: {
                            1502224087221: {
                                actual: {id: 1502224087221, description: "Description of product"},
                                validationError: {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            list: {
                page: 1,
                page_count: 1,
                page_size: 20,
                total_items: 8,
                items: [
                    {}
                ],
                loading: false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to have this store structure.

How I can describe this with typescript interfaces.

I mean there are multilevel nested objects and each can have some custom properties.

Or maybe there is a better design for ngrx store.

API looks like this

api.com/user - this gives users list

api.com/user/[id]/products - this gives user products list

api.com/user/[id]/products/[id] - this gives user concrete product

I tried somthing like this

```
export interface EntityInfo<T1, T2> {
  actual: T1 | T2;
  persist: T1 | T2;
  validation: any;
  error: any;
}

export interface State {

  selectedId: number | string;
  isLoading: boolean;
  entities: {
    [ id: string ]: {
      self: EntityInfo<User, UserResponse>
      product: {
        selectedId: number | string;
        entities: {
          [ id: string ]: EntityInfo<Product | ProductResponse>
        }
      }
    }
  };

  list: {
    items: any[]
  };

}
```

here I'm forced to have property 'self' for parent Entity

Comment: make an interface for objects that are the same? what have you tried so far? where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'll update the question and add what I'v tried.

Comment: please add that to the question not as a comment. :)

Comment: I'v updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

Making the **self** property optional might helps:

```
...
self?: EntityInfo<User, UserResponse>
...
```